# Should the images size be adjust to the same before visual features extraction using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am new to computer vision and trying to build an image classifier to classify the images from different datasets. I'm going to extract visual features of these images like LBP histogram, color histogram using OpenCV. Since these images are crawled from different websites, they have different image sizes (e.g `136x215` vs. `266x382`). Should I adjust the images to the same size before extracting the features?

The code for extracting LBP histogram:

```
img_array=cv2.imread(img)
img_gray=cv2.cvtColor(img_array,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
lbp=feature.local_binary_pattern(img_gray,8,3,method='uniform')
(hist,_)=np.histogram(lbp.ravel(),bins=np.arange(0,11),range=(0,10))
hist=hist.astype('float')
eps=1e-7
hist/=(hist.sum()+eps)
hist=hist.reshape(1,-1)
```

The code for extracting color histogram:

```
image=cv2.imread(img)
image=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
color_hist=cv2.calcHist([image],[0,1,2],None,[8,8,8],[0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])
color_hist=cv2.normalize(color_hist,color_hist).flatten()
color_hist=color_hist.reshape(1,-1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: 
If you want to use the LBP histogram, then **yes**.

It actually depends on the feature descriptor you are using, as some rely on a grid system while others just look at the whole image distribution:

- For the **color histogram** you should be fine, since you analyze the
  color distribution, which is independent of the image size. The
  resulting feature vector should always have the same dimensions as
  long as you use the same color model and the same bin size.
- When calculating the **LBP histogram** you are in fact dependent on the
  image size, since you divide the image into a grid of cells which
  have a fixed pixel size. Each cell will yield you a 256-dimensional
  feature vector. When using the same grid size a bigger image will
  result in more cells, which will then result in a bigger feature
  space for your whole image.

As you can't use feature vectors of different dimensions for your classification, you will need to make sure that your descriptor always produces a vector of the same size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just tried yesterday, input an image with different size and calculated the LBP histogram, it was true that I got different feature vectors. You are right that if the images have different sizes, the shape of the array of LBP is also different.

Comment: But I also did an experiment on color histogram, the outcome changed if I resized the image.

Comment: @ZhangQing then you are probably also using grid cells to calculate the color histogram.